# I try to parse some sensor data sended from LoRa LoRa.readString()

Tags: arduino-ide

I need to parse se message recived from a LoRa Sender in a LoRa reciver.
I don't have any problem to print the all string  in the serial
For ex: "29.56,1004,20"
But I'm unable to parse the "String LoRaData = LoRa.readString();" in an array to send them as separate datas tu use them on the Oled screen o to send them with MQTT.

My actual code is this:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <LoRa.h>
#include <Wire.h>  
#include "SSD1306.h" 
#include "images.h"

#define SCK     5    // GPIO5  -- SX1278's SCK
#define MISO    19   // GPIO19 -- SX1278's MISO
#define MOSI    27   // GPIO27 -- SX1278's MOSI
#define SS      18   // GPIO18 -- SX1278's CS
#define RST     14   // GPIO14 -- SX1278's RESET
#define DI0     26   // GPIO26 -- SX1278's IRQ(Interrupt Request)
#define BAND    868E6

SSD1306 display(0x3c, 4, 15);
String rssi = "RSSI --";
String packSize = "--";
String packet ;

void logo(){
  display.clear();
  display.display();
}

void loraData(){
  display.clear();
  display.setTextAlignment(TEXT_ALIGN_LEFT);
  display.setFont(ArialMT_Plain_24);
  display.drawString(0 , 15 , "Received "+ packSize + " bytes");
  display.drawStringMaxWidth(0 , 26 , 128, packet);
  display.drawString(0, 0, rssi);  
  display.display();
  }

void cbk(int packetSize) {
  packet ="";
  packSize = String(packetSize,DEC);
  for (int i = 0; i < packetSize; i++) { packet += (char) LoRa.read(); 
  }
  rssi = "RSSI " + String(LoRa.packetRssi(), DEC) ;
  loraData();
}

void setup() {
  pinMode(16,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(2,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(16, LOW);    // set GPIO16 low to reset OLED
  delay(50); 
  digitalWrite(16, HIGH); // while OLED is running, must set GPIO16 in high

  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("LoRa Receiver Callback");
  SPI.begin(SCK,MISO,MOSI,SS);
  LoRa.setPins(SS,RST,DI0);  
  if (!LoRa.begin(868E6)) {
    Serial.println("Starting LoRa failed!");
    while (1);
  }

  //LoRa.onReceive(cbk);
  LoRa.receive();
  Serial.println("init ok");
  display.init();
  display.flipScreenVertically();  
  display.setFont(ArialMT_Plain_16);
  delay(1500);
}

void loop() {
  display.clear();
  display.setTextAlignment(TEXT_ALIGN_LEFT);

  // try to parse packet
  int packetSize = LoRa.parsePacket();
if (packetSize) {
  // received a packet
  Serial.print("Recived packet '");

  // read packet
  while (LoRa.available()) {
  String LoRaData = LoRa.readString();
  Serial.print(LoRaData); 
  display.drawString(0, 0,  "Reciving.... ");
  display.drawString(0, 20, "message: ");
  display.drawString(0, 40, String(LoRaData));
  display.display();
  delay(1500);
}

// print RSSI of packet

  Serial.print("' with RSSI ");
  Serial.println(LoRa.packetRssi());
  String packetRssi_to_send = String(LoRa.packetRssi());
  display.clear();
  display.drawString(0, 0,  "Sinial Quality ");
  display.drawString(0, 40, "Rssi = ");
  display.drawString(50, 40, String(packetRssi_to_send));
  display.display();
  delay(1500);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect a problem with `LoRa.readString()` API.  I changed:

```
String LoRaData = LoRa.readString();
```

to

```
LoRaData = LoRaData+(char)LoRa.read();
```

Example:

```
// wait for LoRa packet
int packetSize = LoRa.parsePacket();
if (packetSize)
{
Serial.println("Paquet recu ");
String LoRaData ="";
while (LoRa.available()) 
{ // tant que le paquet LoRa arrive
LoRaData = LoRaData+(char)LoRa.read();
}
```